# Cannot resolving error "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print the output of some other functions to a new sheet in Excel using the following code:

```
Function WriteArrayToOutput(ByRef hour_array As Variant, value_type As String, my_month As String, day_type As String, current_row As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    
    With Sheet6
        .Range(current_row, 3).Value = my_month
        .Range(current_row, 4).Value = day_type
        .Range(current_row, 5).Value = value_type
        
        For i = 1 To 24
            .Range(current_row, i + 5).Value = hour_array(i)
        Next i
    End With

End Function
```

Every time I try to run the code I get the error

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

and debug points to the line .Range(current_row, 3).Value = my_month. I cannot seem to figure out how to fix this. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: nevermind.  You want `.Cells` not `.Range`

Comment: And since you are not returning anything to the the caller, this can be a sub instead of a function.

Comment: You can use `Resize` and avoid the `For i` loop.

Comment: ^^^^: `.Cells(current_row, 6).Resize(,24).Value = hour_array`

Answer (score 1):

Putting the comments into an answer:

```
With Sheet6
    .Cells(current_row, 3).Value = my_month
    .Cells(current_row, 4).Value = day_type
    .Cells(current_row, 5).Value = value_type
    .Cells(current_row, 6).Resize(,24).Value = hour_array
End With
```